# Could contacts class in navigator be used in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I am building a contact manager app using TypeScript. I am tring to use navigator.contacts class to get them.
The problem is that there is an error whenever I add it to my code. I searched everywhere about this problem, but I nowhere found a solution.
The error is:

```
Property 'contacts' does not exist on type 'navigator'
```

Every help would be welcomed :)

Answer (score 0):

navigator.contacts is not supported by TypeScript. A quick fix is using bracket notation to escape type check.

```
const contacts = navigator["contacts"]
```